# Fedora 21 texstudio fails with symbol lookup error

Tags: fedora, dynamic-linking, texstudio

I just installed Fedora 21 on a laptop, and among other things I installed Texstudio. While the install seems to work fine in general, I get absolutely no reaction from this single program. I have tried the following:

1. Remove and reinstall.
2. Remove and reinstall using `.rpm` provided at webpage of Texstudio.
3. Open a single `.tex`-file.

None of the above give any reaction whatsoever. Texworks works fine. Being an inexperienced user I do not know whether or not this will be of any help, but simply typing `texstudio` in the terminal gives the following:

```
texstudio: symbol lookup error: texstudio: undefined symbol: _ZN20QFutureInterfaceBase13setThreadPoolEP11QThreadPool
```

Comment: Usually this is a missing library (the sort `ldd /path/to/texstudio` will list), though I have no idea what library that symbol would belong to.

Comment: Did you install Texstudio from a Fedora package or from somewhere else? If somewhere else, please tell us where (preferably with a link).

Comment: I installed it by 'yum install texstudio'.

Comment: This is a little confusing — you say you used an ".rpm provided at webpage of Texstudio". But that's not what you get if you do `yum isntall texstudio`... _that_ would give you the RPM provided by Fedora, including dependencies.

Comment: I did both several times.

Comment: I had a similar problem on my archlinux. I downloaded and installed the latest version from http://www.texstudio.org/ rather than using `pacman` or any other package manager.

Comment: If using GDM or KDM, have you checked .xsession-errors?

Comment: @AndrewThompson please show us output of following commands (paste them into terminal) : `ldd $(which texstudio)` (as mentioned by @thrig ) 2. `strace $(which texstudio)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the .rpm provided at the Texstudio web page is not quite compatible with the system you're running (its Qt libraries in particular).   Specifically there is a problem with one of the Qt functions:

```
~$ echo '_ZN20QFutureInterfaceBase13setThreadPoolEP11QThreadPool' | c++filt
QFutureInterfaceBase::setThreadPool(QThreadPool*)
```

In your position I'd do one of two things:

- Ask for help on a Texstudio mailing list, IRC channel or other support forum (see for example https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/texstudio-list)
- Build the package from source [by following the instructions here](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Compiling/)